B/W Movie where kids play (live) in the rubble of buildings and have adventures
This is an old English-language, live-action, black-and-white movie.
There are a bunch of young kids, probably age 6-10, who play (live?) in the rubble of buildings. They have adventures and call out to each other to warn of trouble/adults.
My guess is the movie takes place in (WWII) blitz-era London based on the the rubble, but I do not remember.
I seem to remember something about a bird's name ("seagull"?) either being in the movie's title or perhaps it's just the way they call out to each other in warning.
I think the movie was a comedy/drama.
(I'm aware this description is woefully short. It's all I've got. I've done lots of googling in the past with no luck. Please leave a comment about how I could improve my question rather than just voting it down and saying nothing. I'm active on other Stack sites and want to be a good community member here.)

Do you (roughly) remember the kids' age?

I think the kids are young, age 6-10. Question updated.

Maybe It can help you: http://www.cftf.org.uk/catalogue/a.html

Possibly more than one film fitting the description. My first thought was Hue and Cry

@Fruitbat - Yes, looking at Hue and Cry on Youtube it must be right. There is an "operation seagull" in it. If you answer the question, I'll accept your answer. Thank you thank you thank you this has bugged me for decades.

@Mort - I missed the "seagull" reference. Probably 30 years since I saw it but the children playing in the rubble stuck.

Hue and Cry (1947) fits the description.
The main characters are a gang of children who play in the rubble of post-war London.
They discover a criminal organisation which is using doctored comic strip stories to communicate. The word "seagull" is used as a password at one point.
It fits with the comedy/drama. Probably more drama than comedy but considered to be the first of the Ealing Comedies. Wikipedia
Poor quality youtube upload:



